# Bolt-Swift: error handling

Tags: ios, swift, bolt

I want to use BoltsSwift (https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Swift).

But I am not able to handle errors correctly.

In the below sample, why the "taskHello2.continueOnSuccessWith" is running instead of "taskHello2.continueOnErrorWith" ?

Thank you

```
func testTask() {
    let taskHello1 = echo("hello1")
    let taskHello2 = taskHello1.continueOnSuccessWith(continuation: { (task) -> Task<String> in
        let taskResult = self.echo("error")
        return taskResult
    })
   _ = taskHello2.continueOnErrorWith(continuation: { (task) -> Task<String> in
        let taskResult = self.echo("Error received")
        return taskResult
    })
    _ = taskHello2.continueOnSuccessWith(continuation: { (task) -> Task<String> in
        let taskResult = self.echo("Success received")
        return taskResult
    })
}

func echo(_ text: String) -> Task<String> {
    let taskCompletionSource = TaskCompletionSource<String>()
    print("=> \(text)")
    switch (text) {
    case "error":
        let error = NSError(domain: "domain", code: -1, userInfo: ["userInfo": "userInfo"])
        taskCompletionSource.set(error: error)
    case "cancel":
        taskCompletionSource.cancel()
    default:
        taskCompletionSource.set(result: text)
    }
    return taskCompletionSource.task
}
```

output:

```
=> hello1
=> error
=> Success received
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `continueOnErrorWith(continuation:)` only runs when there is an error—the task is faulted.

In your `testTask()` function, `taskHello1` is executed—or succeeded—and hence *'hello1'* is printed to console.

In code:

```
let taskHello2 = taskHello1.continueOnSuccessWith(continuation: { (task) -> Task<String> in
        let taskResult = self.echo("error")
        return taskResult
    })
```

since `taskHello1` had already **met success**, the code inside the closure **is executed** and *'error'* is printed.

Inside code:

```
_ = taskHello2.continueOnErrorWith(continuation: { (task) -> Task<String> in
    let taskResult = self.echo("Error received")
    return taskResult
})
```

since `taskHello2` had **not met error**, the code inside the closure **is not executed** and *'Error received'* is not printed to console.

Similarly in code:

```
_ = taskHello2.continueOnSuccessWith(continuation: { (task) -> Task<String> in
        let taskResult = self.echo("Success received")
        return taskResult
    })
```

since `taskHello2` had **met success**, the code inside the closure **is executed** and *'Success received'* is printed.

Comment: thank naeemjawaid  for your answer.
It is exactly what I don't understand: 
Since taskHello2 is the result of taskHello1.continueOnSuccessWith which return the result of self.echo("error") which return a faulted task, taskHello2 should be a faulted task, not?
If not, what have I to do to have taskHello2 as a faulted task ?

Comment: I up my question. @naeemjawaid ?